# Cublic Spline Interpolation of Phase Space Plot

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spline, cubic

I am creating a phase-space plot of first derivative of voltage against voltage: [image: 1]

I want to interpolate the plot so so it is smooth. So far, I have approached this by interpolating the voltage and first derivative of the voltage separately with time, then generating phase space plots.

Python Code (toy data example)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate

interp_factor = 100
n = 12
time = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
voltage = np.array([0, 1, 2, 10, 30, 70, 140, 150, 140, 80, 40, 10])

voltage_diff = np.diff(voltage)
voltage = voltage[:-1]
time = time[:-1]

interp_function_voltage = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(time, voltage, kind="cubic")
interp_function_voltage_diff = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(time, voltage_diff, kind="cubic")

new_sample_num = interp_factor * (n - 1) + 1
new_time = np.linspace(np.min(time), np.max(time), new_sample_num)

interp_voltage = interp_function_voltage(new_time)
interp_voltage_diff = interp_function_voltage_diff(new_time)
```

I would like to ask:

a) is the method as implemented reasonable?

b) is there a better method by interpolating directly in the phase-space? e.g. interpolating with voltage as x and voltage_diff as y? I do not think this makes sense, because the voltage values are not uniformly spaced and there may be repeated voltage values. I also tried the scipy parametric interpolation methods (e.g. scipy.interpolate.splprep) but these threw input value error. I expect (it would be nice to have this clarified) because this is raw data, rather than well behaved parametric functions.

I guess more generally, I am wondering if it makes sense to somehow do the interpolation in the phase-space to make use of the direct relationship between voltage and voltage_diff for interpolating / smoothing.

Many thanks

Comment: I found an interesting package for cubic spline with user-defined smoothness level:
https://github.com/espdev/csaps
I am not sure it works also with non-monotonic x-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is reasonable, but your difference will be biased, maybe the best approximation for the difference could be `(v[i+1] - v[i-1])/(2*dt)`

Another approach is using Fourier transform smoothing

```py
def smoother_phase_space(y, sps=1, T=1):
    Y = np.fft.rfft(y)
    yu = np.fft.irfft(Y, len(y)*sps).real * sps
    dyu = np.fft.irfft(Y * (2j * np.pi * np.fft.rfftfreq(len(y))), len(y)*sps).real
    k = np.arange(len(yu)+2) % len(yu)
    return yu[k], dyu[k] * sps / T

v, dv = smoother_phase_space(voltage, sps=1)
plt.plot(v, dv, '-ob')

v, dv = smoother_phase_space(voltage, sps=4)
plt.plot(v, dv, '-r')
plt.plot(v[::4], dv[::4], 'or')
v, dv = smoother_phase_space(voltage, sps=32)
plt.plot(v, dv, '-g')
plt.plot(v[::32], dv[::32], 'og')

try: # the data computed in the original post
    plt.plot(interp_voltage, interp_voltage_diff, '--')
except:
    pass
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer thans very useful. So to confirm, you would suggest to take the derivative using a central difference method before interpolation as described above (or smoothing with the Fourier transform method - thanks for this will look into it further).